# Д has the sound of a "d" or "b" in ДOM?

Tags: произношение

Going through [Alphabet - LearnRussian](http://learnrussian.rt.com/alphabet/) I found the sound of **Д** in *ДOM* to be of the English letter **b** (*bom*). Which go me confused with **Б**.

[Cyrillic alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets#Common_letters) states that it has the sound of **d** (*dom*)

> /d/

Is the sound Д in ДOM an exception to this rule? Or am I getting wrong? Or is the pronunciation not so correct?

Comment: I also hear _bom_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. *Дом* has the sound of **d** (dom)